# modwsgi - Precompiled Binaries for Python 2.4?

Tags: python, django, apache, windows-xp, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install Django using Apache and modwsgi on Windows XP.  The problem is our whole development environment uses Python 2.4.

[This page explains how to install modwsgi on Windows](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows) but it doesn't link to any precompiled binaries for Python 2.4.

Anyone know of anything, or a workaround?

Comment: You might be able to build from source instead, but I don't know if modwsgi 3.0+ (the first to have windows makefile support) are compatible with Python 2.4 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions in that page about compiling from source code. Simply copy the makefile for 'win32-ap22py26.mk', calling it 'win32-ap22py24.mk' and make changes to paths to the compiler. This is required as Python 2.4 requires an ancient version of Microsoft C/C++ compiler (VS2003 I think). If you don't already have that compiler you will be out of luck as free express version for that no longer available (if it ever was).

Hopefully that will be enough for it to work, if not and compiler complains about unknown options, you may have to tweak the makefile compiler flags.

If you get it working, please submit back via mod_wsgi issue tracker the modified makefile for possible inclusion in future mod_wsgi version.